# Value class to keep object type for later casting?

Tags: java, reflection, types, casting

I am working on a project that uses ontology to launch algorithm. In other words, the parameters/return value of an algorithm are retrieved from a semantic database so that they can be launched using SPARQL queries.

Let's say I want to get the result of such an algorithm after its execution, which has a specific type, but I have to store it in a very generic way. I would do `Object result = myAlgorithm(param1, param2, ...);`. This does not allow me to store the type of the result for later casting though. I am thinking of a solution, but I am not sure how legitimate it is in Java:

```
public class Value {
   Object o;
   Class<?> type;

   public Value(Object o, Class<?> type) {
       this.o = o;
       this.type = type;
   }

   Class<?> getType() { return type; }

   Object getO() { return o; } 
}
```

The return type of the algorithm is also stored in the database. I know this sounds a bit convoluted, but I hope you understand what I want to do.

Comment: Why can't you keep *type* as a `String` and based on it's value, convert the result into *appropriate* type?

Comment: I thought of that as well. I am not sure which solution is more elegant. I only thought that keeping the type directly would allow me to avoid converting from `String` to `Class<?>` all the time.

Comment: It's not clear to me what kind of processing is supposed to be done with the value; how would you cast it, and what are you going to do with it if the type is unknown?

Comment: If both the algorithm returning the type and the code converting the result into the specified type are under your control, then using string is *simpler*. If none of the things are under your control,  like @daniu says, I am not sure how your code will even work. What if your algo returns a `FooBar` class and your converting service doesn't know that class or uses an older version?

Comment: What I do is I pretty much retrieve the template of the algorithm from the database and, using switch/case based on its name, I launch it. The `AlgorithmLauncher` class has to provide a result after the algorithm execution is done, but only after retrieving the template does it know what the type of the result is. I think I will just have the `result` attribute which will be of type `Object` and a `type` attribute which will be of type `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Each object already keeps it's type in `result.getClass()` method thus you don't need `Class<?> type` field. In your processing code you can do

```
if (result instanceOf <SomeSubtype>) {
     <SomeSubtype> resultCasted = (<SomeSubtype>) result;
}
```